# Resize image before upload c# xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin-studio

Im using xamarin mobile to develop a social network, and i want to resize image before upload. Something like instagram photos. 
Any suggetions ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UIImage has a [Scale](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=M%3AMonoTouch.UIKit.UIImage.Scale%28System.Drawing.SizeF%29) method that will resize an image

```
public UIImage Scale (System.Drawing.SizeF newSize, float scaleFactor)

public UIImage Scale (System.Drawing.SizeF newSize)
```